# MacOS error: -67050 on Authd

Tags: high-sierra, error

After the upgrade to HighSierra, my mac has been running very sluggish and stuttering at times. There is little CPU usage and randomly in any application I'm in, the mac will lock up for a few seconds. It comes in about 1-5 minute intervals and doesn't seem to be apparent to task switching. I've tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC as well as doing a normal cleanup. I can't seem to find out what the issue is which is left me through system logs to find fixes. Does anyone know what causes the `authd` process to have error -67050?

```
default 18:20:05.830736 -0500   authd   MacOS error: -67050
default 18:20:05.855901 -0500   authd   MacOS error: -67050
default 18:20:05.928897 -0500   authd   MacOS error: -67050
default 18:20:06.340587 -0500   authd   MacOS error: -67050
default 18:20:06.389022 -0500   authd   MacOS error: -67050
default 18:20:06.727845 -0500   authd   MacOS error: -67050
default 18:20:06.779068 -0500   authd   MacOS error: -67050
```

I also get these errors too:

```
fault   18:22:11.738440 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.740690 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.741266 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.741574 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.742119 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.743030 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.743254 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.744856 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.745434 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.745951 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.746792 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.747125 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
fault   18:22:11.747889 -0500   iconservicesagent   Failed to find icon image named: <private> for size: (32.000000,32.000000) scale:(1) variant: 0
error   18:22:57.812316 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:23:07.844266 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
```

Edit: (Adding More logs and link to apple thread of similar issue https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8231920 )

```
    deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280

error   18:30:31.233493 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:30:31.233488 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.233613 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.233747 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.233876 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280




error   18:30:31.227622 -0500   deleted volume validation failed for <<(null)>>
error   18:30:31.227944 -0500   deleted volume validation failed for <<(null)>>
error   18:30:31.230678 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.231116 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:30:31.233356 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.233493 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:30:31.233488 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.233613 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.233747 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.233876 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:30:31.607446 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:31.607605 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:31.607760 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:36.799792 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:30:42.783715 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:30:45.872691 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:45.872856 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:45.873035 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.067364 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.067517 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.067666 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.074829 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.074991 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.075147 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.086292 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.086435 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.086596 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.092990 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.093135 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:46.093290 -0500   WindowServer    Error: Unable to acquire capabilities, return code: 0x2006
error   18:30:48.039489 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:30:50.110114 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:30:57.822160 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:31:01.374677 -0500   deleted volume validation failed for <<(null)>>
error   18:31:01.374899 -0500   deleted volume validation failed for <<(null)>>
error   18:31:01.375372 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:01.375451 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:01.375524 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:01.375633 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:01.375744 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:01.375860 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:06.504135 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:31:22.872020 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:31:25.150954 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   18:31:30.084813 -0500   deleted volume validation failed for <<(null)>>
error   18:31:30.085016 -0500   deleted volume validation failed for <<(null)>>
error   18:31:30.087332 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:30.087445 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:31:30.089065 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:30.089104 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:31:30.090620 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:30.090665 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:31:30.092125 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:30.092165 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:31:30.093657 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:30.093696 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:31:30.095250 -0500   deleted fsctl error: Operation not permitted, using HARDCODED low disk threshold 10737418240 for volume_size: 1000345825280
error   18:31:30.095293 -0500   sandboxd    Sandbox: deleted(712) deny system-fsctl 0x4a12 [Duplicate; no report will be generated.]
error   18:31:30.199664 -0500   sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
```